# Как вывести текст из html-файла в php-шаблон страницы Битрикса?

Tags: php, html, битрикс

На сервере есть файл `/docs/test-text.html`.
В нем запись `<div class="sample"><p>Пример текста</p></div>`
Через `<div class="sample">` в CSS-файле задаются нужные стили.
Как надо в php-шаблоне прописать скрипт, чтобы данный текст уже готовый, с примененными стилями, выводился на странице сайта?
**CMS Битрикс**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод `IncludeFile`.

Описание и примеры: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cmain/includefile.php